# Windows 11 Start Button Image Location

Tags: windows-11

I am looking for the location of the Windows 11 Icon used for the Start button. In older versions (Windows 8.1) this icon is present in twinui.dll. However, I can not seem to find it in Windows 11.

I have searched in various '.dll'-files and attempted to find the icon using the process called inspect.exe'. However, this did not yield any result.

Is anyone aware of the current start button icon position in Windows 11? I would like to attempt to adjust this icon.

Comment: Try Resource Hacker App.    http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: There are lots of icons in shell32.dll.mun in the Icon Group Folder using Resource Hacker on my Windows 11 Insider machine.

Comment: Thank you. However, it doesn't seem to contain the Windows Start Button Image. I also verified files like 'imageres.dll'. This contains almost everything, except what I'm looking for.